# Body entity with PathParam in JAX-RS

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I'm trying to resolve some issue with RESTful webservices in Java EE 7.

In some place in my application I have method like this:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void setType(JsonObject typeJson) {
    ...
}
```

In the other:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String retrieveList(@PathParam("idType") Integer idType) {
    ...
}
```

And both are working as expected. However now I would like to combine them but I don't know how. I would like to create method like this one:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addPart(JsonObject part, @PathParam("idType") Integer idType) {
```

So one parameter should be created from body entity of my request and second form PathParam. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the method parameters matters. Do this:

```
public void addPart(@PathParam("idType") Integer idType, JsonObject part)
```

Comment: Please provide more information or a link documenting why order matters.  Thanks.